# I was writing code for basic REST API route and I don't have access to my response from frontend

Tags: node.js, json, rest, express

I am writing code for basic backend authentication, specifically registering user. I am testing my route by REST Client in VS code.
But the problem is that my route is not getting access to res.body ( the JSON data I am sending).

**Here is my route**

```
    router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  try {
    // check if user exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: "User already Exists" }] });
    }
    const avatar = gravatar.url(email, { s: "200", r: "pg", d: "mm" });
    user = new User({
      name,
      email,
      avatar,
      password,
    });
    //encrypt password
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
    await user.save();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error");
  }
```

**This is the error and empty req.body**

*Server started
Database connected Successfully!
{}
Illegal arguments: undefined, string
*

**And this is JSON data i am sending**

What seems to be the problem here?

*POST http://localhost:5000/api/register
Content-Type: application/json
{
"name": "hello",
"email":"hello@gmail.com",
"password": "0987654321"
}*

Comment: Please do not send images of your code. Edit your answer and copy-paste your code into a codeblock (highlight the code and press `Ctrl`+`K`).

Comment: Are you using [`body-parser`](https://npmjs.com/package/body-parser)? It used to be built in with Express but no longer, and is used for parsing request bodies. Install it, require it (`const bodyParser = require("body-parser");`), and use it (`app.use(bodyParser.json());`). Then try requesting again.

Comment: @code - Uh, it's still built-in to [express](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express) `app.use(express.json())`.  To the OP, this type of middleware is required to read and parse the body of your response and populate `req.body`.

Comment: @jfriend00 right. After some research Express >= 4.16.0 has re-added it which was deprecated.

Comment: @code the fact that i wrote simple get request above it and it works. but this doesnt. router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("hello there");
});

Comment: It's probably because you didn't add the JSON body-parser. As @jfriend00 mentioned you need to add `app.use(express.json())` to your main server file.

Comment: I am currently using app.use(express.json). And tried with body-parser. didnt work

Comment: `app.use(express.json)` is NOT correct.  It should be `app.use(express.json())` and it has to be placed before the route that wants to use `req.body`.  Please show ALL relevant code IN your question pasted in as text.  That's how this site is supposed to work and its how you give yourself the best chance of getting an answer quickly.

Comment: What does `console.log(req.body);` show?

Comment: @jfriend00 it shows empty object { }. As i said, my simple get route was working. I made a new route and paste the previous code inside it and it works now. Maybe a bug?

Comment: No, it's not a bug in Express or nodejs.  It was a bug in your code or how you had things ordered.

Comment: @Talha - A GET request will not have anything in `req.body`.  The body is used by POST, PUT and others.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is; is your express app setup correctly? Are there any POST endpoints before this with route "/" that could interfere with the posted code? How are you sending requests? I recommend using Postman or Insomnia. Are you definitely sending a POST request? Does the server definitely receive the request you send? If so maybe it's not reaching this endpoint.

Comment: @Tony definately sending post req bcoz it give endpoint error if method is different. Also it is reaching the endpoint bcoz its console logging the empty req.body. It is working now as i copied the code and made a new route and paste it